# Set initial selected rows in Angular Kendo UI grid with rowSelected

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid where you are able to select individual rows by clicking a checkbox which adds them to an array; however, I am wanting to initially set selected rows based on whether or not the `dataItem` for each row is in a specified array called `selectedAccounts`.

I have tried using `[rowSelected]="isRowSelected"`, but using this method would not allow me to check/uncheck the selection checkbox.

I need to be able to set the selected condition initially and change the selection if needed. It's also worth noting that I do not have an issue when I start with nothing in `selectedAccounts`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltshoj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is a stackblitz for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had everything set up correctly, but I was wrong with the way I was using `isRowSelected` in the typescript file. I originally had:

```
public isRowSelected = (e: RowArgs) => this.selectedAccounts.indexOf(e.dataItem) >= 0;}
```

The above code would always return false while still showing `selectedAccounts` correctly.

After making the changes below, `selectedAccounts` could be read properly and allowed me to toggle the checkboxes as needed while updating the `selectedAccounts` array and without causing any additional problems.

```
public isRowSelected = (e: RowArgs) => { 
  return this.selectedAccounts.find(f => e.dataItem.accountId === f.accountId) ? true : false;
}
```

I hope this answer is helpful for others. I have updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltshoj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) to reflect the correct code.